# I compiled a setup project with VS2017 on Windows 10. Can it run on XP?

Tags: c#, installation, visual-studio-2017, windows-xp, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created a setup project using Visual Studio 2017 and compiled it on Windows 10. It is written in C# WPF and the target framework is `.NET Framework 4`. The target platform is `Any CPU`.

Now that I have compiled the setup project, I am trying to run the MSI for it on Windows XP. The MSI runs successfully and installs the program, but the program will not open. I am being shown an error message box that says:

`MyProgram has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.`

According to the computer events, a `NotSupportedException` error is occurring:

```
Application: MyProgram.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NotSupportedException
Stack:
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.set_SecurityProtocol(System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)
   at MyProgram.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at MyProgram.App.Main()
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for how to fix this problem? .NET Framework 4.0 is already installed on my Windows XP machine. Is there a setting in VS2017 that I need to change?

Comment: Do you have a line of code somewhere that's trying to set `SecurityProtocol`? Maybe to something like Tls12?

Comment: if you use TLS, [install this update on XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows)

Comment: @itsme86 Yes. In my `OnStartup` method in App.xaml.cs, I have the following line: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; //TLS 1.2`

Comment: install the update, setup the reg keys and test the application now.

Comment: The bigger problem is, why are you even supporting win xp when the vendor has already dropped support long ago

Comment: @Steve the embedded versions of XP still have support until 2019

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in Visual Studio target platform, it have to be `X86` otherwise it don't work in xp. The others thinks looks ok.